# bash filename completion hangs because it is searching in unrelated directories for unrelated files

Tags: linux, bash

When I type

```
(module load /scratch/userName/productName/modules/d
```

followed by a tab in order to get

```
(module load /scratch/userName/productName/modules/debug
```

bash hangs for some time and does not accept input.
If I use strace to debug this, I can see that bash is calling stat() on more than 5000 (unrelated) files in 800 (unrelated) directories.
Could anybody explain this to me? Or even better, explain how to tell bash to only search in the specified directory?

edit:
The modules directory exists and contains only two normal files (debug and release). All of the parent directories are normal directories.

edit:
I guess this has something to do with bash ability to forward filename completion to the client being used. In this case this is module but I've also seen it for git.

Comment: I never heard about such behaviour, is it possible you are dealing with symlinks, creating infinite loops?

Comment: You have to check what the completion specification for `module` is: `complete -p module`. It seems to supply its own completion function as it doesn't seem to be part of [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) – or maybe it defaults to file completion in an unfortunate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody somewhere registered some bash function to perform filename completion for the client module. In order to disable this I added the following line into my ~/.bashrc:

```
complete -o default module
```

Thanks to 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w
for the hint!